unable to upgrade postgres extensions
AWS RDS Postgres database on v12.17 is upgraded to v16.1, as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html#postgresql-extensions-16x am trying to upgrade pg_cron and pgaudit extensions but it keeps throwing the same error, how to upgrade them?
postgres=> select version();
                                                 version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 16.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=> select * from pg_extension;
  oid  | extname | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion |         extconfig         | extcondition
-------+---------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+---------------------------+---------------
 14501 | plpgsql |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.0        |                           |
 16410 | pg_cron |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.6        | {16425,16423,16447,16445} | {"","","",""}
 16413 | pgaudit |       10 |        16412 | t              | 1.4.3      |                           |
(3 rows)
postgres=> select * from pg_available_extensions where name in  ('pgaudit','pg_cron');
  name   | default_version | installed_version |             comment
---------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------------------
 pgaudit | 16.0            | 1.4.3             | provides auditing functionality
 pg_cron | 1.6             | 1.6               | Job scheduler for PostgreSQL
(2 rows)

postgres=> ALTER EXTENSION pgaudit update to "16.0";
ERROR:  extension "pgaudit" has no update path from version "1.4.3" to version "16.0"
postgres=> ALTER EXTENSION pgaudit update to "16.0.0";
ERROR:  extension "pgaudit" has no update path from version "1.4.3" to version "16.0.0"
postgres=> ALTER EXTENSION pgaudit update to "16.0.1";
ERROR:  extension "pgaudit" has no update path from version "1.4.3" to version "16.0.1"

postgres=> ALTER EXTENSION pg_cron update to "1.6.1";
ERROR:  extension "pg_cron" has no update path from version "1.6" to version "1.6.1"


pgaudit
As per a comment by a pgaudit developer:

Since pgaudit does not maintain any state (e.g. pgaudit tables) we have no plan to provide upgrade scripts between major versions. You should drop/create extension when you upgrade.

So basically to upgrade, the suggestion is to simply execute:
DROP EXTENSION pgaudit;
CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit;

I would suggest testing if it behaves as expected after doing this.
pg_cron
Even though there are separated releases for versions 1.6.1, 1.6.2, etc. the actual extension version within PostgreSQL stays at 1.6. As can be seen in the control file. This means, you are already at the latest version. That can also be seen by the fact, that the default_version matches the installed version in your output.
